# How to resolve issue of loading web application in OC4J (10.1.3.5) that err and says - can't find the class oracle.jbo.JboException?

Tags: java, exception, web-applications, oc4j

How to resolve issue - while loading web application in OC4J (101.3.5) the application server can't find the class oracle.jbo.JboException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to JDeveloper>Tools>ADF Runtime Installer and chosse the OC4J home.
JDeveloper will install every package needed for OC4J standalone.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://iadviseblog.wordpress.com/2007/04/19/deploying-adf-application-to-standalone-oc4j/) was the most promising link after searching for `oc4j JboException not found` on the web (google). Hope it helps to solve your problem.